# Unlocking the alternative side-quests?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

Does anyone have a consistent way of getting Mireille's/Gatekeeper's missions in Chapter 9? (Ie. "The Price of Thievery" and "Shear's Counterattack")? Every guide I've read online contradicts another one.

I followed the steps in PowerPyx's guide on my first playthrough:

- Sam Dialogue (Chocobo Cowboy): When describing Tifa to him pick “She’s great at handling the books”.
- In Wall Market, don’t talk to the guy in front of the hotel and don’t talk to the hotel receptionist.
- In Wall Market, Ignore the Johnny Discovery Event (where he runs away) and head straight for the main objective.
- When Sam does the coin flip, pick “Heads”.
- Pick the most expensive massage “Luxury Course – 3000 Gil”
- When Aerith asks how you like her outfit “Looks comfortable”.

PowerPyx is usually pretty reliable, but I follow these instructions and I did NOT get the alternative missions. On my next playthrough I just picked the following options:

- She's in great shape
- Didn't talk to the hotel people
- Ignored Johnny
- Heads
- Luxury
- Alright

And I still didn't get the alternative missions. I'm about to start my third and I don't know what to select... :(

IGN's  guide says:

- Do not participate in Sam's coin toss
- Choose the Expensive Massage Course

Gamerant's guide says:

- Choose "No deal" during Sam's coin toss.
- Receive the "Luxury" from Madam M.
- Say "It matter what I think?" or "Looks comfortable" when asked about Aerith's dress.
- Complete the Vagabond Johnny discovery side quest.

Another guide says:

- Hotel guy: How much?
- Sam: Tails
- Massage: Luxury
- Outfit: It matter what I think?

Yet another says:

- Don't talk to the hotel guy
- Sam: Heads
- Massage: Luxury
- Outfit: Comfortable

Surely someone knows the **100% definitive** way to unlock them properly? All evidence seems to suggest it's completely random? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems [Game8.co's guide](https://game8.co/games/Final-Fantasy-VII-Remake/archives/286191#hm_4) has the answer. Phew! This worked for me:

[image]